# The most natural paragraph

Tags: style

Could you choose the most natural paragraph,  please?

> 1. I will come to your place as soon as I am done with the selling of the/our house. Don’t get bored without me. It’s a/the beginning of /a/the/ our new life.
> 2. I have to finish all big deals with the selling of the/our house.
>      Dont be bored without me alone. It’s a beginning of /a/the/ our new life.
> 3. I have to finish all my stuff connected with the house sale, don't get bored without me! It’s a beginning of /a/the/ our new life.

Comment: Hi Monica. I think this question would fit better at [writers.se].

Comment: Monica, this question seems to be a critique of sorts, and those require [more specific guidelines](http://meta.writers.stackexchange.com/questions/166/what-are-the-guidelines-for-asking-for-a-critique-of-my-work) to be acceptable questions on Writers. Can you tell us more about what you're looking for? "Most natural" is vague and difficult to nail down. What are your specific concerns? Can you tell us more about the context this sentence will be in?

Comment: I'm afraid rephrase requests are off-topic; see [meta](http://meta.writers.stackexchange.com/questions/535/are-requests-for-rephrasing-on-topic) for more info.